# Azure API manager Try it works on deprecated portal but get "Unable to complete the request" from new portal

Tags: azure, wso2-api-manager, apim

We have migrated products to the new API Manager portal and all seems to be ok apart from some endpoints. E.g. on an end point to get an auth token when using Try it from the old portal it gets a 200 response. But the exact same request from the new portal gets a 500 and it shows a message "Unable to complete the request". Doing the same request in postman works.

Does anyone have any ideas how this could be happening?

Looking at the request in dev tools it appears the body is being sent as a stream, whereas in the original it is being sent as JSON.

Can't see any options to set to get this to work though.

Many thanks for any help

Looking in dev tools at what gets sent... in the old portal as expected it's this:

```
{"headers":[{"name":"Host","value":"blahblah.azure-api.net"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"},{"name":"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","value":"blahblahblah","secret":true}],"httpMethod":"POST","host":"blahblah.azure-api.net","path":"blah/auth/creds","scheme":"https"}

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

In the new portal it is getting sent like this..

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="requestPackage"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"url":"https://blahblah.azure-api.net/blah/auth/creds","method":"POST","headers":[{"name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"},{"name":"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","value":"blahblahblah"}],"body":{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,10,32,...tons more data here......125]}}
```

Comment: can you please provide the screenshot

Comment: Added the request body for each portal. Weirdly the request works in postman, in azure and in the deprecated portal.. Only the new portal "Try it" functionality doesn't work